# Tomcat form based authentication not protecting catalina.out logging to browser

Tags: tomcat

My two-part goal is to:
1. Log Tomcat's logs (e.g. catalina.out to the browser) - Successful
2. Require authentication for those log files - Unsuccessful

Part 1 is successful after the following change:

> Add file tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/logs.xml
>
> With the following configuration:

```
<Context override="true" docBase="/opt/tomcat/logs" path="/logs" />
```

Logs can be seen with the path:
http://www.domainname.com/logs/catalina.out

Part 2 is not successful after making the configuration changes below. The file is not protected by form-based authentication in the browser (i.e. there is no redirect to login when accessing http://www.domainname.com/logs/catalina.out).
Would the root cause be that the logs directory relative context?

Here are the configuration changes that I made:

> 2A. Within tomcat/conf/tomcat-users.xml
>
> Add the following configuration:

```
<role rolename="role1"/>
    <user username="roleUser1" password="PASSWORD" roles="role1"/>
```

> 2B. Within tomcat/conf/web.xml
>
> Add the following configuration:

```
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>Security Constraint</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Profile Area</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/logs/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>role1</role-name>
            </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>Form-Based Authentication Area</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/loginPage</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/errorPage</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>

<security-role>
    <role-name>role1</role-name>
</security-role>
```

Comment: I think that you've identified the crux of the issue. I'm trying to require Authentication for the default Tomcat app server log directory, rather than a web app. The log directory is not an app. What would be the proper location for Authentication protection of the default logs directory for Tomcat? As an aside, it's OK if all logs/* directories in all web apps are protected with Authentication required.

Answer (score 1):

Your application context path is `/logs`, so your `<url-pattern>` should be set to `*` instead of `/logs/*`.

Why not protect the whole URL space, anyway? This should be a 100% administrative application.

**EDIT 2018-08-27**

*It's critically important that you not modify Tomcat's `conf/web.xml`*. This is the default deployment descriptor for *all web applications on the server*. It is **not** some kind of configuration that covers the server as a whole. So, attempting to protect `/logs` from within there actually protects the URL prefixes `/logs/*` within each application separately, and not the single application you have decided to place under `/logs`.

Instead, you should be modifying the application's `WEB-INF/web.xml` deployment descriptor.

So, go back and restore Tomcat's `conf/web.xml` to its original state, and then put your custom configuration into the `/logs` application itself. I wouldn't use `/opt/tomcat/logs` as the `docBase` for the application. Instead, I'd deploy the `logs` application into `webapps` as usual, and configure it to use `/opt/tomcat/logs` as a read-only [resource](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/resources.html) (try using `PreResources`).

Comment: Thanks for the response!

My application context path defaults to:
"/opt/tomcat/webapps"

Rather than:
"/opt/tomcat/logs"

Setting the <url-pattern> to * will require authentication on the entire app server for all URLs/URIs.

This is not a 100% administrative application.

My goal is to only require authentication on the URL/URI requests to the logs directory: 
http://www.domainname.com/logs/*

Comment: @RaceChasers You are confused about the terminology. The "context path" is a part of the URL and is only coincidentally related to the path on the filesystem where your application resides. You have created an application exclusively for serving log files: it's appropriate for that application to always require authentication. You aren't configuring the whole app server... just that one application (`/logs`).

Comment: **Oh, wait**. I just realized you've been modifying Tomcat's `conf/web.xml`. Updating the answer to suit.